# Displaying images with php from the URL

Tags: php, image, url, upload

Well, I've been on nearly all the posts regarding this issue. I still can't seem to get this working.

I'm basically following this:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

I've got it all working and even managed to get the uploaded picture to display on a php page.

The problem is really, is that I'd like it so that it wouldn't just display the last picture you uploaded, but instead any picture that is in the "uploads" folder.

I'd like to do this in a separate php from the tutorial and the URL would look something like this:

http://myexample.com/display.php?pic=ImAPicture

This way, all the pictures in the uploads folder can be displayed as long as you have the name.

I've played about with it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Please refer to the tutorial to know roughly how I'm working with it.

---

To Sharky, I am unable to reply.
I tried your code but I got an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fl/an/de/flanderskiller.com/public_html/display.php on line 12

I deleted the }

and then I got a new error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fl/an/de/flanderskiller.com/public_html/display.php on line 14

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Show us what **your** code is doing, rather than pointing us to some tutorial which shows "roughly" how you're doing it. Nobody is going to read the tutorial and try to guess at the changes you might have made.

Comment: no changes, just additions. The code would supply nothing new but what's already in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your image and echo it with header Content-type: image/jpeg or image/png like this:

```
<?php
    $image = file_get_contents("path/to/image.jpg");
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your display.php

```
<?php

    $uploads_folder = "/home/yourUnixUsername/public_html/uploads/";        
    $web_folder = "/uploads/";

    $image_requested = $_GET['pic'];  // filename from url

    $images = array();

    if(file_exists($uploads_folder.$image_requested)) // if that image exists, get every image from that folder
    {

        if ($dh = opendir($uploads_folder))
        {
        $inc = 0;

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                if (!is_dir($uploads_folder.$file))
                {
                    $images[$inc]=$web_folder.$file; // construct a web path to image
                    $inc++;
                 }
             }

             closedir($dh);

         }
    }

    foreach($images as $an_image)
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$an_image.'">';
    }
?>
```

not been able to test this but i think it will work!

Comment: Thank you Sharky! I tried your code but I got an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fl/an/de/flanderskiller.com/public_html/display.php on line 12

I deleted the }

and then I got a new error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fl/an/de/flanderskiller.com/public_html/display.php on line 14

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: @Ash this code has not any '}' bracket problems i think there is something else in your code that you added, be sure to have indentation in your code so you can easily see where a block starts and ends

Comment: Thanks Sharky!
I only know AS3, CSS, and html. I only started Php yesterday. So I'm having a little bit of trouble. If you would take a look at http://flanderskiller.com/upload.html Once you upload, you'll be directed to http://flanderskiller.com//upload_file.php And then we have http://flanderskiller.com/display.php?pic=image.jpg.
Please help, thank you

Comment: @Ash if found a small typo in my code there is a missing `)` at the end of line `if(file_exists($uploads_folder.$image_requested) ` i corrected that in the code, try again :)

Comment: Hey Sharky! No errors this time :D
http://flanderskiller.com/display.php?pic=image.jpg
This displays all images which have been uploaded, instead of just one. What's good though, is that when on http://flanderskiller.com/display.php?pic=fff.jpg it doesn't display anything because no picture called fff.jpg exists.